# Regular expression for IFSC code(first four alphabet and then 7 digit.)

Tags: javascript, regex

IFSC Code description:

1. Exact length should be 11
2. First 4 alphabets
3. Fifth character is 0 (zero)
4. Last six characters (usually numeric, but can be alphabetic)

E.g.

> SBIN1234567

Here is what I tried but its not working.

```
("^[^\s]{4}\d{7}$")
```

Comment: Please describe "not working". You seem to be using a string literal instead of a regex literal, which can be a great source of issues if you don't escape backslashes.

Comment: By "alphabet" do you mean "letters of the English alphabet"?

Comment: 1."Not working"  I meant its accepting other then alphabet too for the first four place. "alphabet "i meant english alphabet.

Comment: This is not a generic solution. In my database I have some ifsc code in which it is not mandatory that it has first four char alphabet and last 6 char has numeric.

Comment: @AbhayKumar  IFSC format mention by you,wrong .Check my answer for format &  regular expression

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about `/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{7}$/`

Check [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/lM4hS9/1)

**Edit**

As per definitions of IFSC code posted here in other answers, it is first 4 characters as digit and remaining 7 characters as alphanumeric , regex would be

[^[A-Za-z]{4}[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$](https://regex101.com/r/C5yj0u/1)

Comment: Thanks Hasan its working but not sure why mine regular expression is not working.

Comment: `\s` defines a space character . `[^\s]{4}` defines any four characters that are non whitespace characters. this means it can be be characters other than alphabets also.

Comment: does not validate BARB0LDALUC

Comment: hi shreyas , requirement asked in question was first 4 characters are alphabet then next 7 characters are digits .. BARB0LDALUC is not the character sequence asked in question ...

Comment: @Shreyas check edited answer and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Well, this is not the correct expression as there is one IFSC code "BARB0RAJVIS" which is valid for Bank Of Baroda.

Answer (score 14):

According to [Indian Financial System Code on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Financial_System_Code)

IFSC Code Format:

1] Exact length should be 11

2] First 4 alphabets

3] Fifth character is 0 (zero)

4] Last six characters (usually numeric, but can be alphabetic)

Try this:-

```
^[A-Za-z]{4}0[A-Z0-9a-z]{6}$
```

Answer (score 9):

As per new rules, RBI changed it's guideline for IFSC Code,

New Format for IFSC Code :
Eg. **ABCD0123456**

The IFSC is an 11-character code with the first four alphabetic characters representing the bank name, and the last six characters (usually numeric, but can be alphabetic) representing the branch. The fifth character is 0 (zero) and reserved for future use. Bank IFS Code is used by the NEFT & RTGS systems to route the messages to the destination banks/branches.

*For Code Validation* :  **"^[A-Z]{4}[0][A-Z0-9]{6}$"**

*For Java*:

```
public static boolean isIfscCodeValid(String IFSCCode) 
{
    String regExp = "^[A-Z]{4}[0][A-Z0-9]{6}$";
    boolean isvalid = false;

    if (IFSCCode.length() > 0) {
        isvalid = IFSCCode.matches(regExp);
    }
    return isvalid;
}
```

where isIfscCodevalid() is common static method, which accepts string as parameter(String email) input from User and matches with regExp for IFSC Code Validation and returns the value as true or false.

Answer (score 5):

Try this it perfectly works with 4 alphabets followed by 6 or 7 digits

> IFSC Code: SBIN1234567
>
> IFSC Code: HDFC0123654
>
> IFSC Code: SBIN123456

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("ifsc", function(value, element) {
    var reg = /^[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6,7}$/;
    if (this.optional(element)) {
      console.log(value);
      console.log(element);
      return true;
    }
    if (value.match(reg)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, "Please specify a valid IFSC CODE");

  $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
      ifsc: {
        required: true,
        ifsc: true
      }

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('valid form submitted');
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <label>IFSC CODE</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="ifsc" value="" id="input-ifsc" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

IFSC Code description:

1. Exact length should be 11
2. First 4 alphabets
3. Fifth character is 0 (zero)
4. Last six characters (usually numeric, but can be alphabetic)

> IFSC Code: BARB0SANAND
>
> IFSC Code: SBIN0123456

Replace the above JavaScript with the code

```
var reg = /^[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6,7}$/;
```

to

```
var reg = /^[A-Za-z]{4}0[A-Z0-9]{6}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

The 5th character has to be a 0 and last six characters can be **alphabetic or numeric** [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Financial_System_Code)

So this should work:
`^[A-Za-z]{4}0[A-Z0-9a-z]{6}$`

Answer (score 0):

IFSC (Indian Financial System Code) code contains 11 characters alphanumeric unique code and is assigned by RBI to the bank branch to identify each branch of every bank in India. The first four alphabetic is bank name, and the last six characters (usually numeric, but can be alphabetic) representing the branch. The fifth character is 0 (zero) and reserved for future use
Find more details of IFSC code from http://www.codeforbanks.com/banks/ifsccode-by-branch/

Answer (score 0):

There are many IFS Codes which are not in such format. For e.g. YESB0CCUB18. You can verify this code by simply putting it on google.

I would recommend not to go for a specific validation, simply validate the length or at maximum validate the length and first four to be characters.

Although not related to the question, but in case you want to search IFS Codes, you can refer this website: https://www.bankifscodes.com

Answer (score 0):

RBI Changed it's guidline for IFSC code, so please follow this Regex in your code,

Regex as per new rules - **^[A-Z]{4}0[A-Z0-9]{6}$**

Sample IFSC Code as per new Guidline - **BARB0SANAND**
IFSC or Indian Financial System Code is an alpha-numeric code that uniquely identifies a bank-branch participating in the NEFT system. This is an 11 digit code with the first 4 alpha characters representing the bank, and the last 6 characters representing the branch. The 5th character is 0 (zero). IFSC is used by the NEFT system to identify the originating / destination banks / branches and also to route the messages appropriately to the concerned banks / branches.

Comment: Basically i prefer to use CAPITAL Letters in such codes, so i didnt added any small character

Answer (score 0):

I found this one working:
`/^([a-zA-Z]){4}([0-9]){7}?$/`

Answer (score -1):

IFSC Code consists of 11 characters but it is not mandatory that the first 4 are alphabetic and the last 7 are numerics.
Yes, in most cases it is true but there are certain cases in which it's not the correct way.
eg. I found one IFSC code "BARB0RAJVIS" for Bank of Baroda. In such case, this expression will return false.

I would recommend to use RazorPay API to fetch/check Bank Details for more information.